# ADB command to show Remove account screen

Tags: android, adb, accountmanager, google-account

I want to add and remove google account from device. Programmatically I heard was difficult. I used following command to show screen to add an account, which is working. However, i am not able to find command which removes / manages accounts. Please suggest correct app/intent to launch from adb (or other alternate possibilities to remove account)

I have tried ACCOUNT_TYPES, EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES etc. abd says -  Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent

This command launches add account settings screen

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
```